# After copying a visual selection, return to original location

Tags: vimscript, vimrc, cursor-movement

My cursor is in the middle of a paragraph when I decide suddenly I need to copy that paragraph:

[image: start]

So I type `vip` to select the paragraph visually:

[image: selected]

Now I hit `cmd+C` to copy to clipboard (this may vary on your system, but shouldn't be relevant to my post's central question), which leaves my cursor at the beginning of the paragraph:

[image: final]

rather than the desired position, which is where it was when I started.

Note the same problem occurs when yanking the selection non-visually with `yip`.

I would like the default behavior to be "return to original cursor position" after doing selection/copy actions like this.  Is there a configuration that makes this possible?

Comment: Yeah, I find this annoying too. I just tend to use marks for that purpose: ```mm "+yap `m``` (Note that ```"+y``` yanks to your system clipboard)

Comment: I find it way useful to have the cursor placed either at the start, or at the end of the yanked zone. After all, what can I now do, with yanked text, and cursor inside it? It doesn't make much sense to do a put/paste now. But, if I want to do that later, it means I could also yank later ... maybe what you need now is just a mark.

Answer (score 18):

A possible solution is to use jumps:

Before yanking or visually selecting you can set a new jump which you'll be able to access after your cursor has moved. To do so use <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>.

Then after your cursor has moved because of the yanking use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> to jump back in the jump list. Also you can see the list of the available jumps with `:jumps` and navigate this list with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>

**To sum up your workflow would be:**

- <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>
- <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>

As using <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>  sets a mark, you can jump to it with <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>.

You can read [`:h mark-motions`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#mark-motions) and [`:h :jumps`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#:jumps) for more information.

Comment: I like this.  Is there a way to make single quote behave like backtick in general, when jumping?  single quote is easier to type, and usually i want to jump to the correct column position as well as the right line...

Comment: @Jonah, I map `<leader>'` to be `\``, which works quite well for me. (I use `<space>` as my leader.)

Comment: @Jonah: As Numeri said a mapping can be a good solution, otherwise if you want to get rid of backtick you can have a look at [`:h 'langmap'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27langmap%27). I'm not saying it's the ideal solution but maybe it could be interesting for you.

Comment: @Johah, I actually swap the single quote and back tick using `noremap ' \``
`noremap \` '` ... This is in my vimrc and works great

Answer (score 14):

You can avoid moving the cursor with:

```
:'{,'}y
```

See `:help range`, `:help mark-motions`, and `:help :y`.

Comment: Nice to know about, but is that what you actually do?  It seems typing the 8 keystrakes, with two brackets, makes this harder than the mark solutions

Comment: That's what I *would* do if I was in your position. But I have no issue with the behavior you describe so I don't actually do that.

Comment: @Jonah You still have the option to create a mapping. Something like `:nmap <key> :'{,'}y<CR>` should do the job.

Answer (score 12):

> My cursor is in the middle of a paragraph

If you've just edited it, the simplest solution is to type <kbd>g ;</kbd> which will position your cursor on the last edit position.

And if you haven't edited the paragraph, you could do a simple replace operation with the same character you are on (e.g. you're on `h`, you type `rh`) to trigger an edit "event" without actually editing anything.

Comment: +1: I always used `'.`, but it can be very useful to navigate between the last changes with `g;` and `g,`.

Comment: Is there a version of `g;` which takes you to the correct column position as well?

Comment: @Jonah that's the behaviour by default. Isn't it working for you? It takes me always to the correct column and line position.

Answer (score 5):

The [vim-easyclip plugin](https://github.com/svermeulen/vim-easyclip) has a setting for this:

> `g:EasyClipPreserveCursorPositionAfterYank` - Default 0 (ie. disabled). Vim's default behaviour is to position the cursor at the beginning of the yanked text, which is consistent with other motions. However if you prefer the cursor position to remain unchanged when performing yanks, enable this option.

It's a bit much for me to install an entire plugin just for this small feature, so I prefer using marks as per my comment.

Answer (score 2):

### vim solution :

[source](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/ekgy47/comment/fddnfl3/)

You can just copy the paragraph to the clipboard with `"+yip`

Instead of selecting the paragraph and copying it just set an auto command with the `TextYankPost` event. In vim, I think you will need a plugin and in neovim, you can see an example below. Basically, the TextYankPost event will highlight your copy for some milliseconds.

If you simply copy you can use this function:

```
augroup yank_restore_cursor
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter,CursorMoved *
        \ let s:cursor = getpos('.')
    autocmd TextYankPost *
        \ if v:event.operator ==? 'y' |
            \ call setpos('.', s:cursor) |
        \ endif
augroup END
```

### Neovim solution:

```
local augroups = {}

augroups.yankpost = {

    save_cursor_position = {
        event = { "VimEnter", "CursorMoved" },
        pattern = "*",
        callback = function()
            cursor_pos = vim.fn.getpos('.')
        end,
    },

    highlight_yank = {
        event = "TextYankPost",
        pattern = "*",
        callback = function ()
            vim.highlight.on_yank{higroup="IncSearch", timeout=400, on_visual=true}
        end,
    },

    yank_restore_cursor = {
        event = "TextYankPost",
        pattern = "*",
        callback = function()
            local cursor = vim.fn.getpos('.')
            if vim.v.event.operator == 'y' then
                vim.fn.setpos('.', cursor_pos)
            end
        end,
    },

}

for group, commands in pairs(augroups) do
    local augroup = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("AU_"..group, {clear = true})

    for _, opts in pairs(commands) do
        local event = opts.event
        opts.event = nil
        opts.group = augroup
        vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd(event, opts)
    end
end
```

NOTE: In both cases, it will only work in normal mode, although being possible to enhance it with some code.

The idea for the neovim solution and the vim solution comes from [this answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/ekgy47/comment/fddnfl3/) on reddit.

Comment: Not sure why you would need a plugin in regular vim but there is https://github.com/statox/FYT.vim

Answer (score 0):

Extending Al.G.'s answer, we can go to required location without editing. Solution is <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>. We will reached to the same position where we was in last insert mode before.

- You are in the middle of the paragraph.
- switch to insert mode.
- switch to normal mode.
- press <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>.
- press <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>.
- switch to normal mode. (<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> will left us to insert mode)

If we want to go to start or end of highlighted text.

```
 :help v_o
```

When you yank the highlighted text, you will also return to normal mode and you may or may not retain the original cursor position.

1. If you start highlighting from higher to lower cursor position(from
   lower line-column number to higher line-column number), you will
   retain original cursor position on pressing <kbd>y</kbd>
2. Cursor will remain to current position if highlight start from lower to higher cursor position.

**Returning to original location after yanking:**
<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> to get previous highlight.

Now you can switch between original and current location in visual mode with key
 <kbd>o</kbd> or <kbd>O</kbd>.

Line and column number of status line will help to know exact cursor position.
Documentation:

```
:help visual-change
```

Comment: This doesn't work for `vip` when the cursor starts in the middle of a paragraph.

Comment: Oh ya I didn't notice it, for now I will edit my answer rather than deleting it.

Comment: @Antony Now it also works for `vip` check my edit.